# Traversing a Doubly Linked Linked List in Java?

Tags: java, linked-list, traversal, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to traverse a doubly linked linked list but i seem to get an infinite loop. My goal is to find the first left most occurrence of an element in the list. I find the element but my program seems to keep looping. The only way to stop it from looping is breaking. There has to be another way. Thanks.
{

```
    Node<E> temp;
    temp = head;

    while(temp.next != null){

        if(temp.value==obj){
            System.out.println("YES");
        }

        else{
            temp = temp.next;
        }

        System.out.println("\nNO");
    }
```

}

Comment: put a `break;` in your if condition. If the value is found it won't come out of the loop and never reach that else statement.

Comment: @piyush121 i know of that solution but there must be another way.

Comment: @P.A. use a boolean variable, or return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to advance in any case. Swap printing "no" and the next assignment:

```
Node<E> temp = head;
while(temp != null) {   // Don't check for next here or miss the last element
  if (temp.value == obj) {
    System.out.println("YES: " + value);
    break;
  } 
  System.out.println("NO: " + value);
  temp = temp.next;

  // Loop check (if needed)
  if (temp == head) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Short variant if there are no loops and you want only one "YES" or "NO":

```
Node<E> temp;
temp = head;

while (temp != null && temp.value != obj) {
  temp = temp.next;
}
System.out.println(temp == null ? "NO" : "YES");
```

Comment: But your loop still keeps looping even if you have found the element. It fixes other bugs in the OP's code, but not that one.

Comment: it still seems to infinitely loop.

Comment: Well OP did not mention whether he needs all occurences or the first one.

Comment: Quote (emphasis mine): My goal is to find the **first left most** occurrence of an element in the list. I find the element **but my program seems to keep looping.**.

Comment: Could your list be a loop? I have added some more output for debugging and a simple loop check

Comment: @P.A. this code keeps looping after the element is found, but not infinitely. If it loops infinitely, then you don't have a list, but a circular data structure.

Comment: breaking works but i was wondering if there was more of an efficient way. Or maybe an explanation as to why i cant seem to reach the end of the LinkedList. It just keeps going searching through it without stopping.

Comment: You can just add the check to the while condition, see second variant. It won't be more efficient -- but shorter (and in my opinion thus more readable)

Comment: thanks, i found the issue, in the while loop i should have had (temp.next.value!=null). Silly error